# How to install two different versions of a gem on two different environments using bundler

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, bundler, gemfile

I would like to install 2 different versions of a particular gem on two different environments, how can I do this. For example I want to install 2.13.0 version of a gem in stage env and 3.1.0 on production env to test the use of two different version gems. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In your Gemfile:

```
group :development do
  gem "gem_name", "2.13.0"
end

group :production do
  gem "gem_name", "3.1.0"
end
```

Scroll to bottom of the page: http://gembundler.com/gemfile.html

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have tried that using groups also but was getting issue when I run bundle install, it says You cannot specify the same gem twice with different version requirements. You specified: gem_name (= 2.13.4) and gem_name (= 3.0.0) not sure why this happening, please suggest. Thanks.